# How change redis to be persistent

Tags: redis

I use `redis`.

I want that the DB will be persistent, but when I kill my process, I notice that the data doesn't recover.

In example, I have 100 keys and values. my process run on id = 26060. When I do:

```
kill -9 26060
```

and run `redis-server` again, all the keys are lost.

I check relevant definition in redis.conf, but don't find anything.

How can I make it persistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your test, you should wait 5 minutes before killing the process if you want it to be snapshotted.

This is the default config for Redis (2.8 - 3.0):

```
################################ SNAPSHOTTING  ################################
#
# Save the DB on disk:
#
#   save <seconds> <changes>
#
#   Will save the DB if both the given number of seconds and the given
#   number of write operations against the DB occurred.
#
#   In the example below the behaviour will be to save:
#   after 900 sec (15 min) if at least 1 key changed
#   after 300 sec (5 min) if at least 10 keys changed
#   after 60 sec if at least 10000 keys changed
#
#   Note: you can disable saving completely by commenting out all "save" lines.
#
#   It is also possible to remove all the previously configured save
#   points by adding a save directive with a single empty string argument
#   like in the following example:
#
#   save ""

save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

Everything about persistence is explained in the [documentation](http://redis.io/topics/persistence)

The file where the data will be saved is defined by the following configuration options:

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb

# For default save/load DB in/from the working directory
# Note that you must specify a directory not a file name.
dir /var/lib/redis/
```

Comment: I wait 24 hours. I use redis 3.

Comment: to add to this answer, you can also trigger a save using the command "bgsave"

http://redis.io/commands/bgsave

Comment: @MiddleWare do you see a dump.rdb file in the directory specified in the "dir" configuration?

Comment: in `/var/lib/redis/`? I can't see nothing. it's empty.

Comment: And it define like this: `save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000`

Comment: in your config you should have:
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir ./

Comment: Also check the log file to see if the rdb file was actually saved/loaded

Comment: @ItamarHaber @Geoffroy: Sorry for the late response. Here is the definitions in my redis.config: `The working directory: dir /var/lib/redis/` and `# The filename where to dump the DB dbfilename dump.rdb`. I still don't see anything in /var/lib/redis/dunb.rdb. In addition im my logs I don't see anything which related to the `dumb.rdb` file.

Comment: Check if the proper config file is loaded by appending it to the start command. "./redis-server [/path/to/redis.conf]" Check for file permission redis:redis. Trigger the snapshot manually "BGSAVE" to check for the file.